# How to ignore digits

Tags: regex

I have a file location

```
 /appl/bcm_prod/u/scratch/markit/markitdownloader_20160420_25918.log
```

I know the variable for the year,month, and day, how do I ignore the rest of the string? 
For example,

```
/appl/bcm_prod/u/scratch/markit/markitdownloader_%Y%m%d_25918.log
```

what do I put for the 25918 id which can change everyday.

Comment: `/appl/bcm_prod/u/scratch/markit/markitdownloader_%Y%m%d_\d+` ... to expand on the comment by @Tushar.

Comment: I tried that and it did not work. I got a open file failed error

Comment: Unable to locate /appl/bcm_prod/u/scratch/markit/markitdownloader_20160420_\d+.log

Comment: What do you actually want to DO? Please describe your programming challenge and include the code you've written so far.

Answer (score 0):

What is the regex flavour?

There are examples below:

```
find /appl/bcm_prod/u/scratch/markit/ -regex ".*/markitdownloader_20160420_[0-9][0-9]*.log" -type f

find /appl/bcm_prod/u/scratch/markit/ -type f | grep "markitdownloader_20160420_[0-9][0-9]*.log"

ls /appl/bcm_prod/u/scratch/markit/markitdownloader_20160420_*.log

ls /appl/bcm_prod/u/scratch/markit/markitdownloader_20160420_+([[:digit:]]).log
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically for regex you could either use `*` or `.*`. So you would put the date as necessary and then `*.log` or `.*.log` depending on your regex version. `*`, depending on the regex version, either means 0 or any or is a wildcard. If `*` isn't the wildcard then `.` is. On bash I would say `logname_date_*.log` is what you are looking for.